# Lowercase an array of strings in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to uppercase an array of strings in a dataframe column.

That's the dataframe I have:

```py
index     home_rooms             
0         [Dining Room, Living Room, Bathroom]                     
1         [Guest Room, Kitchen, Game Room] 
2         [Storage Room, Family Room, Bedroom] 
3         [Dining Room, Living Room, Bathroom] 
4         [Guest Room, Kitchen, Game Room]
5         [Storage Room, Family Room, Bedroom] 
6         [Dining Room, Living Room, Bathroom] 
7         [Guest Room, Kitchen, Game Room] 
8         [Storage Room, Family Room, Bedroom]
```

And that's the dataframe I need:

```py
index     home_rooms             
0         [dinig room, living room, bathroom]                     
1         [guest room, kitchen, game room] 
2         [storage room, family room, bedroom] 
3         [dinig room, living room, bathroom] 
4         [guest room, kitchen, game room]
5         [storage room, family room, bedroom] 
6         [dinig room, living room, bathroom] 
7         [guest room, kitchen, game room]
8         [storage room, family room, bedroom]
```

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 df.home_rooms = df.home_rooms.astype(str).str.lower()
```

or

```
 df['home_rooms'] = df['home_rooms'].str.lower()
```